# Creating a \newcommand for a tikz diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

The document I'm writing is full of diagrams of arrows, therefore I'd like to create a newcommand \diagram that avoids me to write every time the settings of the tikzpictures. I put

```
\newcommand{\diagram}[2]{ 
\begin{tikzpicture} [baseline=(current bounding box.center),
grade/.style={sloped,fill=white,inner sep=1pt,font=\tiny},
equal/.style={-,double distance=3pt}]
\matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes, 
             row sep=2em, column sep=2em,
             text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.25ex]
{ #1 };
  #2
\end{tikzpicture}
}
```

so that in the code i should just write 
`\diagram{%matrix_of_nodes}{%paths}`.

For example

```
\diagram{A & B \\
         C & D \\}
        {\path[->,font=\scriptsize]
         (m-1-1) edge (m-2-2);}
```

But when I compile the file (I'm using TexMaker) it returns me the error

> "! Package pgfbasematrix Error: Single ampersand used with wrong catcode."

And it highlights the line where the edge is defined. This problem does not occur if I write the whole script, so I don't understand where the problem could be.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: I think it is a bad idea to pass the entire tikz code as an argument. What about using `\newenvironment{diagram}` instead of a macro?

Comment: That's what I was about to suggest: it seems a much more natural way of doing this.

Comment: @cfr still, I just realised, the problem arises because of the first argument, which contains ampersands...

Comment: @Bordaigorl Yes. You can get around that but I think an environment would be better here anyway.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm quite new to latex and I didn't know of that possibility, nor that having ampersands within an argument could be a problem (I also created a \newcommand for matrices and it worked fine). Thanks for your help anyway, I'll just create a \newenvironment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem arises from the use of `&` in the argument, which is problematic since they are a special character and PGF wants to treat them in a special way.

A solution could be to use environments (which I find nicer anyway) and a trick to avoid needing an argument:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\newenvironment{diagram}{
    \begin{tikzpicture} [baseline=(current bounding box.center),
    grade/.style={sloped,fill=white,inner sep=1pt,font=\tiny},
    equal/.style={-,double distance=3pt}]
        \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,
                     row sep=2em, column sep=2em,
                     text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.25ex]
}{
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{diagram}{A & B \\ C & D \\};
        \path[->,font=\scriptsize]
                 (m-1-1) edge (m-2-2);
    \end{diagram}
\end{document}
```

If you want you can also change the character used to delimit columns using the `ampersand replacement` key:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\newenvironment{diagram}[1]{
    \begin{tikzpicture} [ampersand replacement=\&,baseline=(current bounding box.center),
    grade/.style={sloped,fill=white,inner sep=1pt,font=\tiny},
    equal/.style={-,double distance=3pt}]
        \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,
                     row sep=2em, column sep=2em,
                     text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.25ex]{#1};
}{
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{diagram}{A \& B \\ C \& D \\}
    \path[->,font=\scriptsize]
             (m-1-1) edge (m-2-2);
\end{diagram}
\end{document}
```

note the absence of the `;` after the argument and the use of `\&` instead of `&`.

With this trick you can also define the macro as you originally intended:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\newcommand{\diagram}[2]{
    \begin{tikzpicture} [ampersand replacement=\&,baseline=(current bounding box.center),
    grade/.style={sloped,fill=white,inner sep=1pt,font=\tiny},
    equal/.style={-,double distance=3pt}]
        \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,
                     row sep=2em, column sep=2em,
                     text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.25ex]{#1};
        #2
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
    \diagram{A \& B \\ C \& D \\}{\path[->,font=\scriptsize] (m-1-1) edge (m-2-2);}
\end{document}
```

But I'd still use environments, it just feels more natural and you avoid troubles when `#2` too has special characters in it.

## If you did that just to avoid repetition in style defs:

You could also reduce redundancy by using styles:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\tikzset{
    diagram/.style = {
        baseline=(current bounding box.center),
        grade/.style={sloped,fill=white,inner sep=1pt,font=\tiny},
        equal/.style={-,double distance=3pt},
        every matrix/.style={
            matrix of math nodes,
            row sep=2em, column sep=2em,
            text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.25ex
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[diagram]
        \matrix (m) {A & B \\ C & D \\};
        \path[->,font=\scriptsize] (m-1-1) edge (m-2-2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now the repetition for each diagram is minimal and you have a lot more flexibility.

Comment: Your first solution was more than adequate so solve my problem, but thanks for the further explanation, it's always useful.

Answer (score 1):

Using `ampersand replacement=\&` seems the best strategy; however, I recommend you to give `tikz-cd` a try:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=2em,column sep=2em]
  A \arrow[dr] & B \\
  C & D
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the advice! However i needed to "compress" the environment because I use special edge/node styles that i have to declare  every time at the beginning of the  diagram, as you can see from the code i posted (the small diagram i drew was just an example to show the syntax of my new command). If tikzcd allows to do that with less effort I'm definitely interested to know about it.

Comment: @LK512 As far as I know, `tikz-cd` eventually translates everything in terms of `\matrix` and edge connections.

Comment: @LK512 if you are mainly worried about setting styles at the start you can have a look in the manual how to define your own that can be used as a shortcut, just as in `my diagram/.style={...your styles...}`

Comment: @LK512 I updated my solution to show you what I mean